# Get last created shape in createjs?

Tags: createjs

I have a demo file that I load into a player output from Adobe Animate.
I want to know if its possible to find the last created shape (or its position or bounds) on the stage in createjs via the ticker?
If so how would I go about doing this?

Edit:
I have a tutorial animation which scrolls the window it is in. Due to the amount of information in the animation is can scroll a long way down, my plan is to get the last shape added to the stage, and scroll to that point if its not on the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "last".

You could pretty easily reverse-iterate the [stage.children](https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Container.html#property_children), and look for the first item that is a shape. If it was a container, you could look for its last child, etc.

Once you have a shape instance, you could rely on its `x` and `y` position, or look into its `graphics` instance. The very last instruction is stored on the `graphic.command` ([docs](https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.html#property_command)), and is an EaselJS Command object, which has parameters depending on what type it is. For example, check out the [Rect command](http://beta.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.Rect.html) that stores the x,y,w,h of the last `drawRect()`.

This will at least give you the last vector drawn by EaselJS.

If you provide more info on what you are trying to do, I might be able to give you more ideas.

Comment: I have a tutorial animation which scrolls the window it is in. Due to the amount of information in the animation is can scroll a long way down, my plan is to get the last shape added to the stage, and scroll to that point if its not on the screen.

Comment: Definitely try what I have suggested to see if you can determine the coordinates. Note that you should use `localToGlobal()` to convert any point in a shape to the global (stage) coordinates.